# How to make a UIView transparent while presenting it from UITableViewCell with UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I presented a UINib (custom AlertView) from UITableviewCell by tapping on UILabel. UINib is having two views, one is for custom alert and the background view is to show an alert view effect by making it transparent.

```
@objc func taptakeYourMedsDescriptionLabel(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let undectableVC = UndetectableAlertVC(nibName: "UndetectableAlertVC", bundle: nil)
    undectableVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(undectableVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

I also gave `undectableVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)` in viewWillAppear of UndetectableAlertVC

Problem: The view is transparent while presenting it but soon after the view is presented it is changing to black color.

Requirement:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
let undectableVC = UndetectableAlertVC(nibName: "UndetectableAlertVC", bundle: nil)
undectableVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

undectableVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
undectableVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.navigationController?.present(undectableVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Welcome please accept this answer by clicking right arrow thanks.